# I need to iterate over two text files and a shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

My first file `screen.txt` contains single letters, such as:

```
d
m
a
o
```

The second file `beta.txt` contains a lot of lines:

```
cvvbbe
etgjiua
qwrfggo
```

The third file `gama.sh` is a shell script

I need to loop over the `beta.txt` file in the following way:

- replace the last letter of every line in `beta.txt` with the first letter from `screen.txt`
- save `beta.txt`
- run `gama.sh`
- replace the last letter of every line in `beta.txt` with the second letter from `screen.txt`
- save `beta.txt`
- run `gama.sh`
- and so on

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Where exactly should the combined input be written? Do you need to modify beta.txt in place, or does gama.sh read the concatenated lines via standard input?

Comment: thank you for caring, i want to modify beta.txt without chang place (replace last letter in every line by first line in screen.txt, then by 2nd letter...

Comment: thank you for caring, i change the question to make it easy, and i don't want to add gama.sh.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat gama.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

awk '
    NR==FNR {
        beta[++nr] = substr($0,1,length($0)-1)
        next
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=nr; i++ ) {
            print beta[i] $0 > ARGV[1]
        }
        print "" > ARGV[1]
    }
' "$@"
```

```
$ ./gama.sh beta.txt screen.txt
```

```
$ cat beta.txt
cvvbbd
etgjiud
qwrfggd

cvvbbm
etgjium
qwrfggm

cvvbba
etgjiua
qwrfgga

cvvbbo
etgjiuo
qwrfggo
```

The above assumes the contents of `beta.txt` aren't too huge to fit in memory, otherwise if the contents of `screen.txt` fit in memory then:

```
$ cat gama.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tmp=$(mktemp) &&
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    NR==FNR {
        screen[++nr] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        $0 = substr($0,1,length($0)-1)
        for ( i=1; i<=nr; i++ ) {
            print i, FNR, $0 screen[i]
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<=nr; i++ ) {
            print i, FNR+1
        }
    }
' "$@" |
sort -k1,2n |
cut -f3- > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" "$2"
```

```
$ ./gama.sh screen.txt  beta.txt
```

```
$ cat beta.txt
cvvbbd
etgjiud
qwrfggd

cvvbbm
etgjium
qwrfggm

cvvbba
etgjiua
qwrfgga

cvvbbo
etgjiuo
qwrfggo
```

That second script applies the DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom to produce output lines in the desired order, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367 for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sed` in a loop, like this:

```
 $ while read letter; do 
    printf '%s\n\n' "$(sed "s/.$/$letter/" beta.txt)";
   done < screen.txt > tmpFile && mv tmpFile beta.txt

$ cat beta.txt
cvvbbd
etgjiud
qwrfggd

cvvbbm
etgjium
qwrfggm

cvvbba
etgjiua
qwrfgga

cvvbbo
etgjiuo
qwrfggo
```

If you want it as a script, you can just save this as `gamma.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tmpFile=$(mktemp)
while read letter; do 
    printf '%s\n\n' "$(sed "s/.$/$letter/" beta.txt)";
done < screen.txt > "$tmpFile" && mv tmpFile
```

Note that this will be extremely slow and impractical for large files. It's fine for the dummy example you gave, but if you need to deal with a few thousand or even hundreds of lines, you should use another language. For example, in Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @letters;
open(my $letterFile, '<', "$ARGV[0]") or
    die("Failed to open letter file '$ARGV[0]':$!\n");
while (my $line = <$letterFile>) {
  chomp($line);
  $line =~ /(.)\s*$/;
  push @letters, $1;
}
close($letterFile);

open(my $dataFile, '<', "$ARGV[1]") or
    die("Failed to open data file '$ARGV[1]':$!\n");

my @data = <$dataFile>;
my $c = 0;
foreach my $letter (@letters) {
  print "\n" if $c;
  foreach my $line (@data) {
    $line =~ s/.$/$letter/;
    print "$line";
  }
  $c++;
}
close($dataFile);
```

If you save the script above as `foo.pl`, you can do:

```
$ perl foo.pl screen.txt beta.txt
cvvbbd
etgjiud
qwrfggd

cvvbbm
etgjium
qwrfggm

cvvbba
etgjiua
qwrfgga

cvvbbo
etgjiuo
qwrfggo
```

Note that this will store all of `beta.txt` in memory which might be an issue for huge files. If that is a problem, then you will need a different approach but that's beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: That first script won't produce the output you say it does (and the output you say it produces has an extra block on the end but that's not really relevant since it won't do that anyway).

Comment: @EdMorton I'm on mobile at the moment, but the output was copy pasted. Granted, I wrote this while drinking the first coffee of the day, so it's even more likely than usual that I've made a mistake somewhere, but that's the output I got and I don't see any obvious mistakes. What's the problem? I'm guessing I hadn't cleared the output file before rerunning while testing, as an excuse for the extra block.

Comment: Ugh, that problem was me running it after I had run my script. Can't overstate how much I hate questions that require changing the input file so you can't easily test multiple times! Anyway,  the problem I see now using the original input file is the same as you show - 1 extra duplicate block at the end. I don't know why, honestly the script seems kinda convoluted for all that it does so it's a little hard to understand given as much effort as I'm willing to put into it.

Comment: I mean, it could just be `while read letter; do
    sed "s/.$/$letter/" beta.txt;
    echo "";
done < screen.txt > tmpFile && mv tmpFile beta.txt`.

Comment: Fixed now, @EdMorton, thanks. And yeah, but I find `printf '\n\n'` clearer than the empty echo.

Comment: You're welcome. IMHO `printf '%s\n\n' "$(sed "s/.$/$letter/" beta.txt)"` is less clear and simple than `sed "s/.$/$letter/" beta.txt; printf '\n\n'` and I expect it'd be slower.